# Why does Django bulk_create return objects without pk?

Tags: django, django-orm

Why does Django `bulk_create` return objects without `pk`'s?

```
In [1]: item_list = [Model(title=str(i)) for i in range(10)]
In [2]: objs = Model.objects.bulk_create(item_list)
In [3]: print(objs[0].pk)
None
```

In the result `objs == item_list`

What sense is there in this?

I mean, this method could return a result of the operation (i.e. `True`, or `False`, or something else), not this useless collection of objects that I already have.

Comment: Running Django 2.2 and this issue still persists

Comment: and Django 3.2...

Answer (score 20):

Quoting from the django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

> If the model’s primary key is an AutoField it does not retrieve and
>   set the primary key attribute, as save() does.

According to django, it creates a list of database records in one shot, but the objects' ids are not retrieved. I think it's good for the situation where you do large insertions without further processing the data.

Answer (score 10):

**As of Django 1.10 [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):**

> If the model’s primary key is an `AutoField` it does not retrieve and set the primary key attribute, as `save()` does, **unless the database backend supports it (currently PostgreSQL)**.

So if you are using Django 1.10+,  and you are not getting primary keys returned, it's because only PostgreSQL supports it.